# Mvc 6 app stops after an exception when not using IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using MVC 6 beta 3. I have deployed a test app on Windows 2008 server.

I am not running this app under IIS, rather using `k web` command to run it.

It keeps running for few hours. When there is an exception in the app, it stop running. Is there a way to keep it running even after exceptions?

Comment: first of all, upgrade to beta4. You are on the old version, judging from the `k` command.

Comment: A workaround would be to have your application write to a log (if you know what the exception is and can handle it) and then have a scheduled procedure/script to detect when the application had an exception and restart the process via powershell. But yes, you need to be on beta4.